# What is opposite for Wait-Process

Tags: powershell

So `Wait-Process` waits for processes to be **STOPPED** before accepting more input.

What is the command that can be used for waiting for a process to be **STARTED** before accepting more input?

Comment: I would look here to get started: [Wait for process to start then loop start-process for another process until started](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a208e86-e5d3-4a53-bbd5-5e7b1845a0e7/wait-for-process-to-start-then-loop-startprocess-for-another-process-until-started?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: Have the process set a state once it has begun and have the other process listen for that state.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from looping get-process until it's successful, here's a way to start an event.  But I'm not sure how to wait on it.

```
Register-CimIndicationEvent -ClassName Win32_ProcessStartTrace -Action {
'Process Start: ' + $event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.ProcessName|Out-Host }

Process Start: notepad.exe
```

Cleanup:

```
Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
Get-Job | Remove-Job
```